# Get javascript to write text exactly where it is

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to get javascript to output html where the javascript code is?

For example

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>header</div>
<div>main

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// print some html here, maybe <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
</script>

</div>
<div>footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Where the end results would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>header</div>
<div>main<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></div>
</script>

</div>
<div>footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand that I can give the containing div and id and then get javascript to insert the anchor take like that, but I just wanted to know if it's possible to do this directly, as in write the html exactly where the javascript is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `document.write('YOUR_TEXT')` for that

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.write('<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>') 
</script>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fAUm2/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although there are a lot of nuances to `document.write`, it'll output its contents immediately after the calling `script` element.

**warning**: document.write will obliterate your DOM once the dom is closed for writing. If you need to call a function asynchronously, you'll have to do DOM manipulation, otherwise `document.write` will rewrite *everything* with whatever it's supposed to output. This leads to unintentional results, which is why it's often discouraged.